# Intricate variable name for userform

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to simplify my code to dynamically check some values and update a bunch of tickboxes.

The tickboxes are sort of a table, their name is "col" & number_of_column & type_of_data
ie:

```
Col1PAM Col2PAM Col3PAM 
Col1RL   Col2RL   Col3RL
```

I tried a simple approach with for...next which works:`

```
For i = 1 To 16

    If ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Setup").Cells(j + 2, i + 1) = 1 Then
        Me.Controls("Col" & i & "PAM").Value = True
        Else: Me.Controls("Col" & i & "PAM").Value = False
    End If

    If ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Setup").Cells(j + 3, i + 1) = 1 Then
        Me.Controls("Col" & i & "RL").Value = True
        Else: Me.Controls("Col" & i & "RL").Value = False
    End If

Next i
```

But I have a lot of column types and I tried to make the column type dynamic:

```
Dim Coltype1 As String
Dim coltype2 As String
Coltype1 = "PAM"
coltype2 = "RL"

For j = 1 To 2
    For i = 1 To 16

        If ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Setup").Cells(j + 2, i + 1) = 1 Then
            Me.Controls("Col" & i & ("Coltype" & j)).Value = True
            Else: Me.Controls("Col" & i & ("Coltype" & j)).Value = False
        End If

    Next i
Next j
```

My syntax is incorrect and after many tries, I can't figure out what would be a proper one. Any advice ?

On a side note, I also tried the for...next approach to declare my coltype1, coltype2... variables but it looks like you can't do that?

Thanks for any tips!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```
Dim arr(1 To 2) As String, ws As WorkSheet, i As Long, j As Long

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Setup")

arr(1) = "PAM"
arr(2) = "RL"

For j = 1 To 2
    For i = 1 To 16
        Me.Controls("Col" & i & arr(j)).Value = (ws.Cells(j + 2, i + 1) = 1)
    Next i
Next j
```

Comment: I had to figure out that ws was declared as workbook instead of worksheet, but works like a charm after the correction! Many thanks!

Comment: No prob, I'm learning vba through stackoverflow and your post really helped me a lot.